# Leaflet/JS: Sidebar Resets When Clicking Outside of Default Scroll

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, leaflet, sidebar

I'm making a Leaflet website for a school assignment. To make it more user friendly on mobiles, I've moved the overlays control menu to an interactive sidebar, opened with a `<button>` (now hidden), like this (sorry for some texts in Czech, but they shouldn't be relevant for my problem): [layers when opening sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKzVo.png).

If i then scroll [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzOmS.png) and click on the encircled symbol, the layer is correctly added, but the scroll level of the sidebar resets back to the first state.

I'd like for my sidebar scroll level to stay the same after clicking on any out-of-scroll symbols. I've tried saving the scroll level when clicking and changing it back afterwards, but the transitions were not smooth, even with minimal timeout.

Is there a way to disable this "auto scroll refresh"? It seems to me that it's somehow connected to Leaflet updating the displayed layer on the map, but I honestly don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that my original idea of saving the scroll position and updating it after clicking was the right way to go, I just needed to adjust CSS property `scroll-behavior`. Here is part of my code which shows the full solution for anyone who might chance upon the same problem:

**Leaflet:**
(one overlay layer, which is part of `overlays` dictionary, later used as an input to `L.control.layers`)

```
// previous overlay layers above
"<table><tr><th><img src='./img/graves.png' onclick='resetScroll()'/></th><td><p>hrobky</p></td></tr></table>":L.geoJSON(graves).setStyle({
     color: "#669999",
     weight: "1",
     fillColor: "#669999",
     fillOpacity: "0.5"
}),
// remaining overlay layers below
```

**JS function** called `onClick` on `<img>` elements i used to activate/deactivate layers:

```
function resetScroll() {
     let scroll_position = document.querySelector(".leaflet-control-layers-scrollbar").scrollTop;
     window.setTimeout(() => {
          document.querySelector(".leaflet-control-layers-scrollbar").scrollTop = scroll_position;
     }, 1);
}
```

**CSS**:

```
.leaflet-control-layers-scrollbar {
     scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

I know that this might not be the most efficient or elegant method of doing what I wanted, but it works nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem with a project, and in the end, I simply reduced the number of buttons, and made their icons a few pixels smaller, so that they would fit on any iPhone, Samsung, Xiaomi, etc.
I will give you an example of the project (early stages), and you can see the result.
**Disclaimer: I am affiliated with this site; it's my personal research website, but there is zero spam there! Danger-free zone guaranteed, LOL!**
Take a look at it, on laptop and phone, and see the difference, and the source code.
[Ancient Rome Leaflet Map, earliest beginnings during the time of King Romulus](https://elcuentoderoma.com/rome/)

Comment: Thank you for that idea, but I really need to keep the amount of layers I'm using :/ I can "solve" it by saving scrollTop parameter to localStorage and then recalling that after clicking on my icons, which returns the scroll level back to where it was, but makes this "jump" movement that's not really pleasant for the eyes :/

Comment: Can you store the Y coordinate value somewhere, when a user clicks (keydown) on the buttons, and just retrieve the value and use it on keyup ?

Comment: Yes you can, I actually used that to solve my problem in the end (it should be somewhere on this thread, I posted it as an answer to my post). You can save it to the local storage of the user's PC, but I chose to simply upload it to a variable, it just feels more user friendly to me not to save anything unnecessary on someone's PC. Also using it in a variable means that it doesn't get stored for later visits/after refresh, so the scroll starts always at the top when opening the interactive legend in a sidebar.